# Angular textbox focus lost event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a textbox and a label. I want to write a function and call this function that in turn call a API service. I am expecting the result object of that service to return name and id which should be binded to the labels below.

```
<input id="text" ng-blur="callMyFunction" type="tel"/>
<label id="name" ng-model="name"/>
<label id="id" ng-model="id" />
```

Could someone please help me how to write onfocusout i.e when a user types a number and then press tab (literally when the textbox is focussed out when some text is entered), I need to have this function triggered.

Comment: I think you're just missing parentheses ng-blur="callMyFunction()"

Comment: Is this angularjs or angular2?

Comment: @Kolby: Sorry, I was after the functionality, I know the concept, but need the exact syntax

Comment: @arthurzp: I mentioned both versions so that any folks can help me who are part of those two groups. I am after angular 1. Can you help ?

Comment: All you need is `ng-model` on that input and you have everything you need in controller to do what is needed.

Comment: @charlietfl: Thank you, yes, slowly building. But still don't know how to pass data of "text" to the javascript

Comment: it's the model value in controller . Study some form tutorials. Same principle

Comment: @charlietfl: Sure thanks

Answer (score -2):

I think I see what you're trying to do now.
You can pass `$event` into your function to get a reference of the element.

This should get you on the right path:

`ng-blur="callMyFunction($event)"`

```
$scope.callMyFunction = function(e){
   var element = $(e.currentTarget);
   var name = element.parent().find('#name');
   var id = element.parent().find('#id');
}
```

https://thinkster.io/egghead/index-event-log